# Laravel uploading image issue

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I am using this code to upload an image file:

```
 $path = 'public/uploads/users/'.Auth::User()->id.'/avatar/';
 Storage::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true);
 Storage::disk('local')->put($path,  Input::file('avatar'));
```

Its working fine, The image is uploaded here:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/storage/app/public/uploads/users/2/avatar/0d8c18a52732bc9b0068102338fbf29b.jpeg
```

In order to display it on the frontend I have to copy this file into `public/storage` . Or I have to delete the `public/storage` folder and the command: `php artisan storage:link` and here is my problem: for each image upload I have to delete the `public/storage` folder and run that command .
Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You juste need to run `php artisan storage:link` once. That create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

After that you can upload as many images as you want and access them from the web.